# Space between two consecutive hhlines

Tags: longtable

While using the longtable and hhline packages, I would need to have space between two consecutive hhlines as in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small
\begin{longtable}{|c||p{0.45\textwidth}||p{0.45\textwidth}|}
\hhline{~|-||-}

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Positive}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Negative}} \\\hhline{~||-||-}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[-9pt]\hhline{-||-||-}

\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Internal}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Strengths}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Weaknesses}} \\\hhline{|~||-||-}

& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
& We are strong! & We are weak! \\\hhline{-||-||-}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[-9pt]\hhline{-||-||-}

\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{External}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Opportunities}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Threats}} \\\hhline{|~||-||-}

& One opportunity & One threat \\
& One opportunity & One threat \\
& One opportunity& One threat\\
& One opportunity & One threat\\\hhline{-||-||-}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In the example above I had to use an empty line ending with `\\[-9pt]` to produce the expected effect. Is there a better way to produce this without adding this empty line ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a blank row you could just use

```
\\[...]
```

no need for the `\multicolumn`.

You could add space between `\hhline` by doing

```
\hhline{===}
\noalign{\vspace{3pt}}
\hhline{===}
```

but here it seems you just want a double line so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

{%\begin{center}
\small
\begin{longtable}{|c||p{0.45\textwidth}||p{0.45\textwidth}|}
\hhline{~|-||-}

\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Positive}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Negative}} \\
\hhline{-:=::=}


\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Internal}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Strengths}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Weaknesses}} \\\hhline{|~||-||-}

& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
& We are strong! & We are weak! \\
\hhline{=::=::=}

\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{External}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textbf{Opportunities}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Threats}} \\\hhline{|~||-||-}

& One opportunity & One threat \\
& One opportunity & One threat \\
& One opportunity& One threat\\
& One opportunity & One threat\\
\hhline{-||-||-}
\end{longtable}
}%\end{center}

\end{document}
```

(Don't put `longtable` in a center environment, it does not centre it, just adds spurious vertical space)